# rem units don't work in webview

Tags: android, css, webview

I've created a simple application using Phonegap for android, that simply loads my website's content. The problem is webview doesn't understand the "REM" css units, even though on the same device when I open the website in chrome browser it works as expected.

The technique I'm using is I set the root font-size in pixels (for example 1px), and everything else using rem units. It looks like when using webview, it has some minimum value for font-size which is far bigger than my value and it multiply all elements sizes by 10-12 times.

Is there a way to fix it without switching to pixels instead of rems?

Code example:

```
body {
    font-size: 1px;
}
.element {
    width: 15rem;
}
```

From the code above, the width of the element should be 15px, which is correct if I open the website in mobile browser, but in webview its bigger than 150px;

**UPDATE**:

I'm almost sure that it has a minimum font-size issue in webview, because I tried the opposite now, I set the root font-size to 15px and .element width to 1rem and it shows everything correctly, means REM units are working if I set root font-size above the minimum limit in webview.

Here is how my website looks in mobile chrome
[[image: Browser]]

Here is phonegap application
[image: Application]

Comment: You might consider posting some CSS and HTML that is not working for you, perhaps with some links to some screenshots showing the proper and flawed behavior. You could try [this `rem` polyfill](https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill) and see if it works with `WebView` or could be tweaked to work with `WebView`.

Comment: Added some code and screenshots to the question. Tried to use the polyfill but it didn't help.

Comment: Could it be that Phonegap is injecting some sort of `reset.css` that is affecting the `WebView` base-font?

Comment: I checked your suspicion that there might be something like a minimum base-font-size for the rem calculations.

And indeed, it looks like for base font-sizes between 1px and 8px there is no difference in the resulting line-height if specified in rem.

So for example:

A base font-size of 3px and a line-height specified with 15rem results in a line height of **not** (3px*15=45px) but (8px*15rem=120px), since 8px seems to be the minimum I observed.

I wonder if you observe the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, in the end I changed the base font-size to 15px and created SASS function that calculate rem units like that:  `@function rem($num) {
    @return ($num/15) + rem
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179357/android-webview-rem-units-scale-way-to-large-for-boxes

Answer (score 1):

Webview increases the minimum font-size by default. This solution works the best for me. Now webview acts like most other browsers with rem units. :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496408/688352