# Android Webview rem units scale way to large for boxes

Tags: android, html, css, unit-testing, webview

**EDIT: This bug is Webview overriding the default minimum font size.
      In my example, Webview sets the minimum font-size to 8px somewhere. The solution is below :)**

Android Webview rem units scale way to large.
All rem units appear 8 times too large and out of place in Android Webview.
The only rem tag that works correctly is font-size:30rem; for text. Everything else
seems to scale way to large. i.e. 100rem = 800px @ 1.0px scale.
Strangely, after I pass 8.0px while scaling, the box starts to enlarge.

This example works on every browser that supports rem units except Webview.
Anyone have an idea?

[image]

Online Example:   http://digitalknob.com/rem.html
JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/aquawicket/71p49ag9/
Android Example:  http://digitalknob.com/remTest.apk

I've tried **mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);**
I've tried **mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);**
I've tried **< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />** and other variations.
I've tried loading a default user style sheet.

**rem.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size:1.0px;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="font-size:16em;">

<button style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;font-size:60px;" onclick="ScaleDown()">-</button>
<button style="position:absolute;left:110px;width:100px;height:100px;font-size:60px;" onclick="ScaleUp()">+</button>
<a id="text" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:220px;font-size:60px;">1.0px</a>

<!-- FIXME: rem units appear 8 times too large and out of place in Android Webview. 
     The only rem tag that works correctly is font-size:30rem; 
     This html file works as expexted on all other browsers. -->
<div style="position:absolute;top:115px;width:100rem;height:100rem;background-color:green;">
    <a style="position:relative;top:30rem;left:16rem;font-size:30rem;">Scale</a>
</div>

<script>
var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
Update_Scale();

function ScaleDown(){
    scale -= 0.5;
    Update_Scale();
}

function ScaleUp(){
    scale += 0.5;
    Update_Scale();
}

function Update_Scale(){
    document.documentElement.style.fontSize = parseFloat(scale).toFixed(1)+"px";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = parseFloat(scale).toFixed(1)+"px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="digitalknob.remTest"
      android:installLocation="auto"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="19"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:label="remTest"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name="digitalknob.remTest.WebviewActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**WebviewActivity.java**

```
package digitalknob.remTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_webview);
        mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); //Debuggable in Chrome
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://digitalknob.com/rem.html");
    }

    @Override public void onBackPressed(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that setting the following webview settings will act as a workaround for this bug.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
```

[setMinimumFontSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMinimumFontSize(int))

These settings really should only be honored for actual text display, not rem based positioning/sizing.  This ***must*** but an android webview bug.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The only limitation is negative font-size.  font-size:1px is the lowest you can go.