# Rem units in android browsers on webview engine

Tags: android, css

I use rem as the width of the element, instead of px and in all browsers it looks good (such as Android Chrome, Android Firefox, iOS Safari, etc.) and allows me to conveniently scale the elements.

But on android, in browsers on the webview engine (such as UC Browser, Opera Mini, stock browser, etc.) everything breaks down, because

> font-size: 1px

simply does not work because of the minimum font size.

They [already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179357/android-webview-rem-units-scale-way-to-large-for-boxes) about this problem and even found the answer, but it is suitable only for mobile applications, not for sites.

I wanted to write a js script that goes through all the elements, their css properties, and if it sees rem, it recounts it. But getComputedStyle gives the result in px and find out where rem was not possible.
Perhaps there are some other ways to fix this?

```css
html {
  font-size: 0.1vw;
}

.block {
  font-size: 25rem;
  width: 500rem;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">I'm 50% width, but not in a webview.</div>
```